# DocumentDb stored procudure collection.queryDocuments not working

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am developping a system for large data scale. Currently, I am testing stored procedure in collection with less than 300k documents.

I am following this example:
[DocumentDB server-side programming: Stored procedures, database triggers, and UDFs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/documentdb-programming/)

"createDocument" and "replaceDocument" are working fine so far. 
But queryDocuments is not working at all no matter how many ways i tried. I tried to put throw exception in many place but throw exception inside callBack are not getting hit at all.

Have anyone used queryDocuments() in stored procedure successfully?

```
function MoveTree(nodeJson, targetParentNodeJson) {
var node = JSON.parse(nodeJson);
var targetParentNode = JSON.parse(targetParentNodeJson);

var collection = getContext().getCollection();
var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();

var count = 0;

//<==Tried put throw exception here and it is hit
var node;
var IsAccept = collection.queryDocuments(
    collection.getSelfLink(),
    'SELECT * FROM Nodes p where p.id  = "' + nodeId + '"',
    function (err, documents, responseOptions) {
        //<==Tried put throw exception here but it is not hit
        if (err) throw new Error(err);
        if (!documents || documents.length != 1) throw new Error("Unable to find node.");
        node = documents[0];
        //<==Tried put throw exception here but it is not hit
    });
//<==Tried put throw exception here and it is hit
```

//...
}

[Screenshot of code with comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spDPn.jpg)

Comment: The variable `nodeId` is never set. Did you mean for that to be targetParentNode._id? Also, you have two `var node`... declared in the same scope. That said, I wouldn't think that either of those would prevent the callback from being called. I would think it would just throw the "Unable to find node" error.

Comment: I meant targetParentNode.id

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages when executing the stored procedure? If so, what are the error messages?

Comment: You can find a working example stored procedure that performs a query here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/3e19ee238215a83c00097fb9c9078cbba0e0939c/samples/stored-procedures/SimpleScript.js

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. I have been quite busy lately. I figured it out that all of these core functions are async with lead to unexpected behaviors. Hence, I my stored procedures will run through all and return way before any of these core functions even finish.

Answer (score 0):

As Larry mentioned, the issue is you have not set the `nodeId` variable... which results in the following error message when run:

`Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception = ReferenceError: 'nodeId' is undefined`

Comment: Hi, that must be node.Id. My mistake of copy paste when doing some testing. But it was not the issue. I figured it out by myself. I added a comment in previous one.